Which function do I need to use for Exploratory Factor Analysis with 4 binary variables?
I have a dataset with 137 observations and 4 binary variables (0, 1). I want to check their factor structure.
I have tried out two possibilities:
Option 1:
fit_efa <- efa(data = df_children_td_first, 
               nfactors = 1,
               rotation = "promax", 
               estimator="WLSMV", 
               ordered = TRUE, 
               output = "efa") 

In this case, however, I get the following warning: "Warning: lavaan WARNING: some estimated ov variances are negative".
These are the Standardized loadings:
                       f1      unique.var   communalities

tom_first_test1_binary  1.007          -0.015           1.015
tom_first_test2_binary  0.789           0.378           0.622
tom_first_test3_binary  0.873           0.238           0.762
tom_first_test4_binary  0.862           0.256           0.744
This may not work.
So I tried:
Option 2:
efa.model <- '
efa("efa")*f1 =~ tom_first_test1_binary + tom_first_test2_binary + tom_first_test3_binary + tom_first_test4_binary
'

fit <- cfa(efa.model, 
           data = df_children_td_first,
               rotation = "promax", 
               estimator = "WLSMV", 
               ordered = TRUE)

summary(fit, standardized = TRUE)

I don't get an error but this output:
Latent Variables:
Estimate   Std.lv  Std.all
f1 =~ efa
tm_frst_tst1_b    1.007    1.007    1.007
tm_frst_tst2_b    0.789    0.789    0.789
tm_frst_tst3_b    0.873    0.873    0.873
tm_frst_tst4_b    0.862    0.862    0.862
How do I need to proceed in this case? I have never seen estimates above 1.
See description above.
